# breeze: unidirectional one-to-many navigation with compound foreign key still not populating in spite of invForeignKeyNames being defined

Tags: breeze

I am currently using Breeze 1.5.3.

I have defined the metadata for my model so that there is a unidirectional one-to-many relationship between two entities `Column` -> `ColumnStatistic`.

When I inspect the JSON returned by my service I see a `ColumnStatistics` collection for each `Column`, but this collection is empty when I inspect the resulting entities.

I'm using EF6 to provide the primary and foreign key information.  The relevant statements in my OnModelCreating method are the following ones.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Column>().HasKey(c => new { c.Owner, c.TableName,  c.ColumnName});
modelBuilder.Entity<ColumnStatistic>().HasKey(s=> new { s.Owner, s.TableName, s.ColumnName, s.StatisticName });
modelBuilder.Entity<Column>().HasMany(c => c.ColumnStatistics).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(s => new { s.Owner, s.TableName, s.ColumnName });
```

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cNLiUrXADC9xXc1Fdhyn?p=preview) for this example. The example is a little more complicated than it needs to be since it contains metadata for entities outside the scope of this writeup, but I clearly see the `Column_ColumnStatistics` relationship in my metadata along with the associated foreign key constraint.

```
"association": [{
        "name": "Column_ColumnStatistics",
        "end": [{
            "role": "Column_ColumnStatistics_Source",
            "type": "Edm.Self.Column",
            "multiplicity": "1",
            "onDelete": {"action": "Cascade"}
        },
        {
            "role": "Column_ColumnStatistics_Target",
            "type": "Edm.Self.ColumnStatistic",
            "multiplicity": "*"
        }],
        "referentialConstraint": {
            "principal": {
                "role": "Column_ColumnStatistics_Source",
                "propertyRef": [{"name": "Owner"},
                                {"name": "TableName"},
                                {"name": "ColumnName"}]
            },
            "dependent": {
                "role": "Column_ColumnStatistics_Target",
                "propertyRef": [{"name": "Owner"},
                                {"name": "TableName"},
                                {"name": "ColumnName"}]
            }
        }
    }
```

All foreign key fields appear in the instances of `ColumnStatistic` returned by my service.  A typical example of this data is the following.

```
{
"$id": "1",
"$type": "Archive.DtoModels.OracleMetadata.Column, Archive",
"Owner": "FUSION",
"TableName": "SGP_STUDENT",
"ColumnName": "CONSOLIDATED_SUBGROUP_CURR",
"DataType": "VARCHAR2",
"ColumnStatistics": [{
    "$id": "2",
    "$type": "Archive.DtoModels.OracleMetadata.ColumnStatistic, Archive",
    "Owner": "FUSION",
    "TableName": "SGP_STUDENT",
    "ColumnName": "CONSOLIDATED_SUBGROUP_CURR",
    "StatisticName": "HasNull",
    "StatisticValue": 0},...]
}
```

Also, when I inspect the `ColumnStatistics` property of the `Column` entity type in my `metadataStore`  I see that `invForeignKeyNames` is correctly defined as the three value composite key that I specify in the metadata.  By design `inverse` is undefined because I intend this to be a unidirectional navigation property from the *one* side to the *many* side only.

Based on my reading of the Breeze release notes, the definedness of `invForeignKeyNames` should be sufficient to guarantee 1 to n navigability in versions >= 1.3.5.  Since `invForeignKeyNames` is defined in my case, the situation appears to be different than that outlined in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056231/breeze-1-to-many-unidirectional-navigation-property-not-populated) closest to mine that I managed to uncover on this site.  Without having yet delved into the breeze source code, I am wondering if the composite keys in my example are part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but breeze does not support navigation with composite foreign keys.

The primary key can be a composite key. A navigation property can be linked to one of the properties of that composite key. But the FK itself can only be one property.

Clearly we contemplated this possibility by defining the `foreignKeys` and `invForeignKeys` properties as arrays. But we delayed implementation (which adds much complexity) until we saw significant demand. In 14 years of tracking this possibility, you are perhaps the first (at least among the few) to have run into it.

You can post a request for this feature on our user voice. But you will need another approach for now.

Do you have a lot of these kind of properties in your model? Is it read-only? If it is fairly isolated you may be able to workaround it by transforming the three-part key into a single part key with client-side manipulation in a `JsonResultsAdapter`. If this idea is remotely appealing, we can work it out together in a follow-up.

Comment: My model _is_ quite simple and read-only, and I'm using DTOs.  So, I can just map the three-part key into a single key (i.e., concatenate parts into a single string with parts separated by a `::`)  when I project to my objects and I've realigned my metadata to reflect the new situation.  Even though it sounds tempting,  I think I can forgo a client-side solution in this instance.  Thanks for your response.